# Different discriminant ideal, what are their applications?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, motivation

Lots of texts online on number theory do not even mention the different ideal. Some do, but then it gets ignored and is never mentioned again. I could not find a single application for it, as if it is just some random concept invented so teachers can make students do computations. I tried to search it, but the word "different ideal" is so common that I keep getting psychology webpages instead. Now, you can calculate the ramification from the difference - but normally to get the difference you need to know the ramification, so that is kind of pointless. I have heard that you can find the genus from the difference, but there is no genus in number field. So what is the point of this?

Discriminant seemed to help with figuring out what the ring of integer is. Is that all? Is there a good example of it being used when more elementary method failed?

Thank you.

Comment: In the setting of local fields, the different ideal (or rather its inverse) arises when studying local duality of the ring of integers.  That is more or less just by definition (and is similar to the meaning of the inverse of the different for number fields), but the point then is that the ideal is closely linked to ramification. Concerning "there is no genus in number fields" see Kida's formula in Iwasawa theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this text will be useful: 
http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/different.pdf